# step_downsample - I am having trouble using the function despite installing packages, copy code from online

Tags: r, r-recipes

I am working on preprocessing and using the step_downsample from recipe on my training set to reduce imbalances between nominal variables.
I am using a version of the Fair's Affairs dataset.
The first step I have taken is intial split, train and test for the data.
The second step I am trying to downsample, step_dummy and normalise the predictors.
I recieve an error from r saying could not find function step_downsample but it looks like I am coding this as per all examples I can find. I have also tried loading themis and recipes to use the function.

I am trying to create a recipe, based on the training data, that will: down sample the data, convert all catagorical predictors to dummy variables, and normalise the predictor variables.

The code that has been written is below

```
affairs_train <- training( affairs_split )
affairs_test <- testing( affairs_split )
head(affairs_train, n=6)
```

```
affiars_recipe <- recipe( affair ~ ., data = affairs_train) %>% 
  step_downsample(affair) %>%
  step_dummy(all_nominal_predictors () ) %>% 
  step_normalize( all_predictors() ) %>% 
  prep()
```

From my reading online I have tried installing multiple packages. I have also tried copying exactly other peoples code, unfortuantely, the error message is recieve is

Error in step_downsample(., affair) :
could not find function "step_downsample"

Comment: Please share a sample of your data using `dput`

Answer (score 1):

You likely forgot to load in the {themis} package along with {recipes} as it contain `step_downsample()`. It should read

```r
library(recipes)
library(themis)

affairs_split <- NULL # Code to generate affairs_split

affairs_train <- training( affairs_split )
affairs_test <- testing( affairs_split )

affiars_recipe <- recipe( affair ~ ., data = affairs_train) %>% 
  step_downsample(affair) %>%
  step_dummy(all_nominal_predictors () ) %>% 
  step_normalize( all_predictors() ) %>% 
  prep()
```